# Excessive PHP Processes

Tags: php, openlitespeed

Recently, I've found my CPU Usage and Number Of Processes extremely high while expecting CPanel. They are constantly staying in the 90% - 100% range, and it is causing my site to run extremely slow and at times throw 500 or 503 errors. I tried running `exec('ps aux | grep php', $output1);` to see all current processes, and I notice there are over 150 process that look like the following:

```
    [0] => UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    [186] => 8913503   809796  807066  0 07:44 ?        00:00:00 lsphp
    [187] => 8913503   809804  733105  0 07:44 ?        00:00:00 lsphp
    [188] => 8913503   809805  733105  0 07:44 ?        00:00:00 lsphp
    [189] => 8913503   809808  807066  0 07:44 ?        00:00:00 lsphp
```

I've coded my site with PHP and have about 43 subdomains. Each subdomain has a cronjob that runs every hour to update the site with new information. Everything that I've found so far suggests that the problem has to do with one of the scripts I run on one of the pages or cron jobs, however I have no idea how to find out what is the problem. My cron job scripts mainly consist of web scraping code that pulls data from other sites. MY hosting is through GoDaddy and they do not provide a terminal option through CPanel.

My question is, how can I view more information about the processes that are currently running so I know what scripts are causing the problem?

Comment: Nobody can say, without knowing what your cronjobs exactly does... and you should note, that most websites won't like automated scraping of their contents, and you'll usually need a permission from the owners to legally do it with a script.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly where a script is taking a lot of time and CPU. But you could use [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) to do some tracing or profiling.

Of course, you don't want XDebug to be running via the web server as it's not a good practice on a production site. But you can run your cron tasks without calling an URL launching the *LiteSpeed* web server. If the script is launched via the command line, then you can have another PHP setting to enable the tracing.

I would personally start off just by the following steps :

1. Add some logging into your cron tasks. Write to a dedicated log
   file for each of your sub-domain. This way you can see if one is
   slower than the others. Just write the date, time and a few comments
   to show when the cron job starts, where it is in the steps and when
   it finishes. You could also log
   [memory_get_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php),
   [memory_get_peak_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) and
   [getrusage()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.getrusage.php).
2. Call your PHP cron task with a low priority with the help of
   *nice* in order to consume less resources and let the web server be
   more reactive :

   ```bash
   /usr/bin/nice -n 19 /usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/private/cron.php
   ```

   You may need to adapt the path to the `nice` and `php` binaries.
   Typically, PHP could be `/usr/local/bin/php`. You may even have
   several versions of PHP installed. To find the paths, you can run
   a PHP script with :

   ```php
   <?php
   header('Content-Type: text/plain');
   print "Path to nice:\t" . exec('which nice') . "\n";
   print "Path to php:\t" . exec('which php') . "\n";
   print "This directory:\t" . dirname(__FILE__) . "\n";
   ```

   Have a look at *GoDaddy*'s help. They may mention the several PHP
   versions and where to find them. If not, via SSH, you could probably
   find them too.
3. Be sure that your 43 cron tasks don't start all together at `**:00`.
   You'll probably have to spread them over an hour and have multiple
   starting times.
4. If you need to reduce CPU consumption, you may need to run your
   cron tasks on another machine (if possible) or use another
   technology (which, I agree, is rather annoying). Perhaps that
   the tracing and profiling could help you optimize your code.
   I imagine that you already use PHP tweeks such as
   [OPcache](https://www.php.net/opcache) and some monitoring with
   [OpCacheGUI](https://github.com/PeeHaa/OpCacheGUI) or
   [opcache-gui](https://github.com/amnuts/opcache-gui). This can
   reduce the load on the server if you didn't enable and size it yet.

   I was also thinking about the usage of
   [APCu](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.apcu.php) to save some
   data into memory and make some things a bit faster, but this only
   works if both the website and the cron task run over the same
   process, meaning that the cron task should be run across the
   *LiteSpeed* web server. So we should probably forget this
   optimization idea.